# callback function call before calling another function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function which calling one API:

```
const response = fetch(APIfunctonName, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(searchRequest),
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    },
})
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(
        (result) => {
            let urlParams = this.getRequests();
            let reqid = urlParams["requested"];
            var newUrl = window.location.href
                .replace(`requestID=${reqid}`, "requestID=0")
                .replace("requestID=0", "requestID=" + result.RequestId); //result.RequestId always have proper one
            history.pushState({}, null, newUrl);
            this.getList(result.RequestId); //sometimes this goes as undefined
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
```

I always get proper requested in the result object, but I don't understand why sometimes I get an old Id in the getList function

Comment: I believe this depends on your api endpoint (`APIfunctionName`). How can we help when we don't know how that endpoint works?

Answer (score -1):

You could use a Promise as follows so that you make sure the proper request is going to be passed to next instruction :

```
let p = new Promise((resolve , reject) => { 

 let urlParams = this.getRequests();
        let reqid = urlParams["requested"];
        var newUrl = window.location.href
            .replace(`requestID=${reqid}`, "requestID=0")
            .replace("requestID=0", "requestID=" + result.RequestId);
             history.pushState({}, null, newUrl);
        resolve(result);   
 }); 

 p.then((result)  => {
     this.getList(result.RequestId); 
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

i think the reason is the defference between sync ajax and async ajax.

if this below ajax `this.getRequests()` is **async**. Your code will get some accidental error.

```js
let urlParams = this.getRequests();
```

1. First solution is change *async* to *sync*.

Your can change this `this.getRequests()` to *sync*.  Your code will work just fine.

2. Second solution is use `await` and `async`.

```js
const response = fetch(APIfunctonName, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(searchRequest),
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    },
})
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(
        async (result) => {
            let urlParams = await this.getRequests();
            let reqid = urlParams["requested"];
            var newUrl = window.location.href
                .replace(`requestID=${reqid}`, "requestID=0")
                .replace("requestID=0", "requestID=" + result.RequestId); //result.RequestId always have proper one
            history.pushState({}, null, newUrl);
            this.getList(result.RequestId); //sometimes this goes as undefined
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
```

Comment: As the issue seems to be related to `result` object and not `urlParams` return by getRequests I don't think this is the root issue. Even if `this.getRequests();` is async, it will not have any impact on what is contained inside `result` object